# Is it possible to set MSBuild properties from within Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm contributing to a fairly large project that uses MSBuild properties to control the build process. I am running some tests from the command line like this:

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:OSGroup=Windows_NT /p:Performance=true
```

And everything is working fine. However, when I try to run the tests from Visual Studio, the `OSGroup` and `Performance` properties are not set, which causes things to not work correctly.

Any idea how I can set these properties before building my `.csproj` file within Visual Studio? It has to be without editing the `.csproj` file, since I don't to accidentally check in any changes I make there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only option besides changing the proj files is to set them as environment variables. I don't think there's any file you can change that wouldn't be checked in normally (like an suo file).

Comment: You'd use the .csproj.user file for that.

Comment: If you open a project in visual studio you really just get a user-interface view on top of the csproj file. As such: no you cannot change anything project-related in VS without modifying the actual project file as well.. @HansPassant you should post that as an answer, it's the most suitable after all and the .user file is basically tailored for this kind of stuff

Comment: Hmm, I don't want to have to answer the next question.  Builds that can only work on one machine owned by one specific team member are never not a mistake.

Comment: Good point indeed..

Comment: Can't you create other configurations  beyond Debug and Release, if you have a reasonable combination set? Like "ReleaseWindowsNT", etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could just add an [external tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx) command which builds using the same command as shown. VS will parse the output just like from it's own builds, so warnings and errors are shown in the Error List etc. Your command would be something like

`msbuild $(SolutionDir)$(SolutionFileName) /p:Configuration=Release /p:OSGroup=Windows_NT /p:Performance=true`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Visual Studio extension and access project properties trough DTE.Solution.Projects and Project.Properties. There is an example here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166172.aspx

VS DTE interface can also be used in a standalone application or Powershell script.